# Screen Dim Event / User Inactivity

Tags: android

first of all, I would like to tell you, what I want to do: I want to get some behavior of iOS on my Android device. Of course, it's just a little detail.

The behavior I talk about is on iOS like that:

1. The user doesn't use the device
2. After a short time, the device dims its screen.
3. Now the user has to tap somewhere on the display to reactivate the device.
4. *THIS IS THE BEHAVIOR I WANT* If the user taps on the screen, the screen

   will just become active again. The tap itself will NOT cause any other action.

On Android, it's almost the same behavior. Except for step 4: If the user taps on the screen to prevent standby, the tap will already cause actions in the app or home screen or wherever you are.

I decided to develop a small Accessibility Service. This service will show an overlay when the device is inactive and dims its display. Clicking on the overlay will just close it. The overlay itself is no problem and it's already working.

My problem is: I don't know how to find out when the display is dimmed because of inactivity.

My ideas are:

1. Listen to the Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF event (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent).
   --> It's working. But it's too late :-( The screen is already completely off when the event has been fired.
2. Check, if the device is inactive/idle.
   --> Is there any possibility to get the status of the whole device? I haven't found anything about that.

Or maybe somebody has completely other ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Greetings

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the window screen on & using a TimerTask, dim the brightness of the window manually by some % every, say 5 seconds...

Then when the taps on overlay, Increase the brightness

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. But I still have one problem: I don't know, when I can start dimming the screen. I need the information when the device becomes inactive. And I really don't know how to get it..

Answer (score 0):

override method dispatchTouchEvent() in your activity
and you will be notified about every touch in your app

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    ev?.let { event ->
        if (event.action == ACTION_DOWN) {
            //start counting user's inactivity
            //or launch a coroutine with delay before screen dimming
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```